# Django - How to change the default queryset in a view if a filter is used?

Tags: django

I have a Django project, in which, in my view, I have this:

```
    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        qs = super(OrderTableView, self).get_queryset()
        if self.request.user.profile.store is not None and self.request.user.is_superuser is False:
            qs = qs.filter(store=self.request.user.profile.store)
        today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
        qs = qs.filter(total__gt=0).filter(address__isnull=False).filter(location__isnull=False).filter(date__date=today).order_by('-date')
        return qs
```

This works correctly, I want only the orders from the day to be displayed when the view loads, and this works correctly.

However, in the view I also have filters for the date, which I want to use to filter the date if the user so chooses. This filter, for example, filters all the dates after the date selected in the filter.

```
    def filter_date(self, queryset, name, value):
        yesterday = datetime.date(year=value.year, month=value.month, day=value.day) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        queryset = queryset.filter(date__gt=yesterday)
        return queryset
```

The problem is that, as far as I understand, the get_queryset method works first, and so, when arriving to the filters, the queryset already excludes all dates that are not from today, which is fine when the view loads, but should not always occur, since sometimes I'd like to include orders in dates other than today, if I'm searching, for instance.

Is there a way in Django to set an initial queryset to a view, but then using a different queryset when the user actually searches for something with filters?

Comment: It did! By accessing the request directly through the get_queryset method, there I can see which filters were used, and change the queryset accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.